# Flutter-windows dart.io not working as expected, errno = 32

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

When trying to delete file's parent folder , obviously it return `OS Error: <message>, errno = 32`:

- using the class `File("path-to-file")` is necessary in my case, it is used to manipulate the file before deletion
- deleting the parent directory return the **error** because the file is opened like before

For example, this code never works:

```
File file = File("<path-to-file>");
file.parent.deleteSync();
```

- I am using the command `flutter run -d windows` to run the project.

Here is the full code for simple demo:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? path;
  bool isAsync = false;
  bool recursive = false;

  final String filePath = "C:\\flutter_demo\\text.txt";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                  value: isAsync,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isAsync = value!;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const Text("use async"),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                  value: recursive,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      recursive = value!;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const Text("recursive deletion"),
              ],
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: isAsync ? deletDirectoryAsync : deletDirectorySync, child: Text("Delete file: '$filePath' parent folder")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void deletDirectoryAsync() async {
    Directory dir = File(filePath).parent;
    await dir.delete(recursive: recursive);
  }

  void deletDirectorySync() {
    Directory dir = File(filePath).parent;
    dir.deleteSync(recursive: recursive);
  }
}
```

- I want to by-pass using a temporary folder to manipulate those files (huge files)
- **I want to force the deletion**

Please, can you help?

Comment: Are you sure that the folder isn't opened (or is the current working directory) of some other process?  I highly doubt that `File(filePath)` opens a handle to the specified file.  AFAIK the `File` constructor doesn't do any work.

Comment: folder not opened and file not opened by other program, you can try and see it by yourself with the code above

Comment: I ran a simple Dart program on my Windows machine: `import 'dart:io'; void main() { File('C:\\path\\to\\some\\file').parent.deleteSync(recursive: true); }`.  It deleted `C:\path\to\some` and all of its contents fine.

Comment: did it work using flutter interface when button clicked? That's my case

Comment: I don't have the Flutter SDK installed, but it shouldn't make any difference.  It's not as if Flutter is using some different implementation for the `File` class.

Comment: It is working fine using dart program but the same code don't work using flutter, I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory is the problem, instantiating a directory opens a handle.
I solved it by changing the `Directory.current` to temp location:

```
//to avoid errno = 32
Directory.current = await getTemporaryDirectory();
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
if(result!=null){
   String parent = 'get specific parent path from result';
   //do works 
   Directory(parent).deleteSync(recursive: true);
}
```

Comment: As the examples in the comments showed, *instantiating* a `Directory` does not open a handle.  Opening a *file/directory picker* would because on Windows, a file/directory picker changes the current working directory of the process.